# How to matched random number using input function

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random, input

How can i matched the random generated number in input function?
my if and else statement don't run because even i inputted the random number, they don't match. here is my code below.

```
import random
randomNumber=[]
length_randomNumber = 6

for i in range(length_randomNumber):
    randomNumber.append(random.randint(0,9))
print(randomNumber)

x = input("Enter the 6 generated number :")
if x == randomNumber:
    print("x and random number matched!")
else:
    print("x don't matched with the random number!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem occurs due to `x = input("Enter the 6 generated number :")`.
The x here is of string type.

What you can do instead is this:

```
for i in range(length_randomNumber):
    randomNumber.append(random.randint(0,9))
print(randomNumber)

x = input("Enter the 6 generated number, seperated by commas :")
x = [int(y) for y in x.split(",")]
if x == randomNumber:
    print("x and random number matched!")
else:
    print("x don't matched with the random number!")
```

Here you convert the input to an integer array and compare.
Above we used a list comprehension to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Your x is by default string, so needed to convert into integer first... & 2nd thing is randomNumber is a list, so condition should be x in randomNumber;

```
import random
randomNumber=[]
length_randomNumber = 6

for i in range(length_randomNumber):
    randomNumber.append(random.randint(0,9))
print(randomNumber)

x = input("Enter the 6 generated number :")
if int(x) in randomNumber:
    print("x and random number matched!")
else:
    print("x don't matched with the random number!")
```

Answer (score 0):

randomNumber variable is a list not an integer , if you are trying to check if an entered value is present in that list of random numbers then change if condition to :
`if int(x) in randomNumber`

if you are trying to form a 6 digit random number , this is not the right way to generate.

Answer (score -1):

your randomNumber is list, you can use operator in to check it. and also convert the x first to integer. like below:

```
import random
randomNumber=[]
length_randomNumber = 6

for i in range(length_randomNumber):
    randomNumber.append(random.randint(0,9))
print(randomNumber)

x = input("Enter the 6 generated number :")
if int(x) in randomNumber:
    print("x and random number matched!")
else:
    print("x don't matched with the random number!")
```